# How to apply a fix to an installed chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using a popup blocker named `JavaScript Popup Blocker`.

Sometimes this extension becomes broken, I have to reinstall it (e.g. it breaks when I add a website with a URL like `http://xxxx:6666/`).

Today, it happen again and I decided to fix the error (last update is in 2013, it seems that author would not fix this error in future). I found the extension folder by chrome extension ID, and made some changes to the source code.

But Chrome says this extension is broken and needs fixing after I restart Chrome. I even repacked the extension and installed again, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself.

Remove `key` in `manifest.json`, remove the `_metadata` folder as well(as [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan) suggest), then repack the extension.

Then Chrome would not say this extension is broken after installing.

Comment: this is really a hack and may break in the future. the real fix is to republish the extension yourself which also shares the fix for other users and makes you famous :) do check the original licence hopefully it permits to modify and republish.

Comment: @ZigMandel I wouldn't call that a "hack" that wold break.

Comment: You really should remove the `_metadata` folder as well.